# Angular Type Script undefined error with parent variable

Tags: angular, typescript

Anyone understand why I am getting an undefined error?

```
export abstract class BaseEditorComponent implements IPropertyEditor, OnDestroy {

  @Input()
  public element: BpmnJS.IRegistryElement; 

--more code here


export class CommonPropertiesEditorComponent extends BaseEditorComponent {

  constructor(
  ) {
    super();
  }

  public get elementId(): string {
    return this.element.id;
  } 

export class ExclusiveGatewayEditorComponent extends CommonPropertiesEditorComponent implements OnInit {

  public model: IUserTaskDef;
  public outGoing: Sequences[];

  constructor(
    private service: ExclusiveGatewayService
  ) {
    super();
    this.model = {} as any;
    this.outGoing = this.getOutGoingSequences();
  }

  public getOutGoingSequences(): Sequences[] {

    return this.service.getOutgoingSequences(this.elementId); //This is undefined.
  }
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at ExclusiveGatewayEditorComponent.get [as elementId] (common-properties-editor.component.ts:16)
>       at ExclusiveGatewayEditorComponent.push../src/app/properties/editors/gateways/exclusive-gateway/exclusive-gateway-editor.component.ts.ExclusiveGatewayEditorComponent.getOutGoingSequences
>   (exclusive-gateway-editor.component.ts:27)
>       at new ExclusiveGatewayEditorComponent (exclusive-gateway-editor.component.ts:22)
>       at createClass (core.js:21148)
>       at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:21027)
>       at createViewNodes (core.js:29387)
>       at createRootView (core.js:29301)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:30309)
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:29819)
>       at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create
>   (core.js:20506)

**If I enter the same function into the html page it works fine and displays the value of element.id**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtId" [(ngModel)]="elementId" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to access `@Input()` properties from constructor, they do not exist at this point. You should do it in `ngOnInit()` method instead.

```
export class ExclusiveGatewayEditorComponent extends CommonPropertiesEditorComponent implements OnInit {

  // ...

  constructor(
    private service: ExclusiveGatewayService
  ) {
    super();
    this.model = {} as any;    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.outGoing = this.getOutGoingSequences();
  }
}
```